# Order Form in MVC - filling out same form for multiple people and saving them as a single order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am working on small web application where a manager can order badges for their team. I have the form and logic of saving a single form to the database done, but I need the ability to save multiple badges to a single order using the same form, then saving that single order of multiple badges to the database as a single order that can be reviewed later. Basically, I need to fill out the form for Bob, than maybe press a "add another person" button and fill one out for Jane who could have completely different info for the badge.

Here is the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class=" page-header">
        <div class=" btn-toolbar pull-right">
            <div class=" btn-group">
                @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                    <button type="button" class=" eButton">Edit Form</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Order Form</h2>

        <div class=" form-group">
            <div class='form-row'>
                <div class='form-group col-md-6'>
                    <label for="user_title">Date</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='form-group col-md-6'>
                <label for="user_firstname">Number of Badges</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumBadge, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumBadge, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>



<div class=" form-group row">
    <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Account Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountNbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">

                @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                }
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=" form-group row">
    <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Account Name 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountName1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountName1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">

                @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                }
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=" form-group row">
    <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Account Name 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountName2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountName2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">

                @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                }
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">ID Number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IDNbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDNbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Holder Type:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolderType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HolderType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Neutron:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Neutron, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Neutron, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Wear Location:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WLocation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Use Period Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UPD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UPD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Series Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Clip Type:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.DropDownList("ClipType", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem {Text = "SL - Slotted Clip", Value = "SL"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "AL - Alligator Clip", Value = "AL"}
           })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Series Color:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.DropDownList("SeriesColor", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem {Text = "GR- Green", Value = "GR"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "BL - Blue", Value = "BL"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "LB - Light Blue", Value = "LB"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "NO - None", Value = "NO"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "OR - Orange", Value = "OR"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "PP - Purple", Value = "PP"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "RD - Red", Value = "RD"}
           })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Frequency Color:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.DropDownList("FreqColor", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem {Text = "GR- Green", Value = "GR"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "BL - Blue", Value = "BL"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "LB - Light Blue", Value = "LB"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "NO - None", Value = "NO"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "OR - Orange", Value = "OR"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "PP - Purple", Value = "PP"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "RD - Red", Value = "RD"}
           })
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group row">
        <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Badge Use:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.DropDownList("BadgeUse", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem {Text = "PA - Participant", Value = "PA"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "AR - Area Monitor", Value = "AR"},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "CO - Control", Value = "CO"}
           })

                <span class="input-group-btn">

                    @if (new string[] { "Bogey@email.com", "user2", "user3" }.Contains(this.User.Identity.Name))
                    {
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Field</button>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

if (User.Identity.Name != "Bogey@email.com")
{
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="submit" value="Draft" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the Model:

public class DraftsModel
    {

```
    [Key]
    public int orderId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number of Badges")]
    public string NumBadge { get; set; }

    [StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 6 characters.")]
    public string AccountNbr { get; set; }

    [StringLength(17, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 17 characters.")]
    public string AccountName1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(17, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 17 characters.")]
    public string AccountName2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(17, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 17 characters.")]
    public string Fname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(17, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 17 characters.")]
    public string Lname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 8 characters.")]
    public string IDNbr { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 2 characters.")]
    public string HolderType { get; set; }




    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 2 characters.")]
    public string Neutron { get; set; }

    public string BarCode { get; set; }

    public string WLocation { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
    public string UPD { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
    public string Sname { get; set; }

    public string CustomerKey { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
    public string ClipType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
    public string SeriesColor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
    public string FreqColor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
    public string BadgeUse { get; set; }


}
public class DraftDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DraftDBContext() : base("OrderForm")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DraftDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DraftDBContext>());

        }

        public DbSet<DraftsModel> Drafts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new OrderModel();
        model.Date = DateTime.Today;
        return View(model);
    }
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "orderId,Date,NumBadge,AccountNbr,AccountName1,AccountName2,Fname,Lname,IDNbr,HolderType,Neutron,WLocation,UPD,Sname,ClipType,SeriesColor,FreqColor,BadgeUse")] ParentModel orderModel)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Orders.Add(orderModel.OrderModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        // raise a new exception nesting
                        // the current instance as InnerException
                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                throw raise;
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(orderModel);
    }
```

I know this is a pretty huge post, but I've put a lot of time into this and this is the last little thing I need to finish! Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: so what problem are you facing? You haven't mentioned what's giving you difficulty, or where in your application the issue is. You haven't actually asked us a question either

Comment: My question is, is there a way to essentially 'clone' the view and then save how ever many filled forms to a single spot in the database? I have a feeling that Jquery might be the way to do it, but I'm not very experienced using it.

Comment: What do you mean a single spot in the database? You mean save them all in one playback instead of one after another with a refresh in between. They'd still need one entry each in the database I would imagine. Yeah you could use jquery or javascript but you'd also need a viewmodel such that it supported holding a list of badge records as opposed to just one. You can probably find examples of this kind of concept online in tutorials etc, or maybe examples of a shopping system where you can add multiple products at once, something like that. Have a Google around